# Работа с массивом объектов и привязкой одних данных к другим на выходе

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Я новичок в JavaScript, только учусь.
Ниже находится объект, который содержит контактную информацию.

```
var contacts = [
  {
    name: "Laurel",
    phone: "123 456 7890",
    email: "laurel@comics.com",
    friends: ["Hardy", "Abbott", "Costello"]
  },
  {
    name: "Hardy",
    phone: "321 654 0987",
    email: "hardy@hardyharhar.com",
    friends: ["Laurel", "Buster"]
  },
  {
    name: "Buster",
    phone: "987 654 3210",
    email: "buster@keaton.ca",
    friends: ["Hardy"]
  },
  {
    name: "Abbott",
    phone: "888 123 4567",
    email: "abbott@whosonfirst.co",
    friends: ["Costello", "Laurel"]
  },
  {
    name: "Costello",
    phone: "767 676 7676",
    email: "costello@imonfirst.co",
    friends: ["Abbott", "Laurel"]
  }
];

/* You should be changing this code */

function findFriend(data, name, field) {

  /* IMPLEMENT ME */

}
```

Мы хотим построить функцию, которая будет принимать три параметра. Первый параметр - сами данные, второй - имя контакта, а третий параметр будет указывать либо «телефон», либо «электронную почту».
Функция примет эти параметры и вернет имя и указанное поле первого друга в списке друзей контакта.
Например, используя данные ниже и указав «Laurel» в качестве первого параметра и «email» в качестве второго,функция будет смотреть на список друзей Laurel и возвращать имя «Hardy» и адрес электронной почты Hardy.
Примеры ожидаемого вывода:

```
console.log(findFriend(contacts, "Abbott", "phone"));// returns {name: "Costello", phone: "767 676 7676"}
console.log(findFriend(contacts, "Buster", "email"));// returns {name: "Hardy", email: "hardy@hardyharhar.com"}
console.log(findFriend(contacts, "Bob", "phone"));// returns "Not found"
console.log(findFriend(contacts, "Costello", "birthday"));// returns "Not found"
```

Самое сложное для меня это как связать данные, которые от нас хотят. Я понимаю логику, но на деле не знаю как это реализовать( да и села в последнюю минуту и не успеваю все сдать в срок( Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: "не успеваю все сдать в срок( Помогите" - не является уважительной причиной

Comment: Раз понимаете логику - начните писать код. Когда появится конкретная проблема, тогда и задавайте конкретный вопрос! Пока что выглядит как *"сделайте за меня"*.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let contacts = [{
    name: "Laurel",
    phone: "123 456 7890",
    email: "laurel@comics.com",
    friends: ["Hardy", "Abbott", "Costello"]
  },
  {
    name: "Hardy",
    phone: "321 654 0987",
    email: "hardy@hardyharhar.com",
    friends: ["Laurel", "Buster"]
  },
  {
    name: "Buster",
    phone: "987 654 3210",
    email: "buster@keaton.ca",
    friends: ["Hardy"]
  },
  {
    name: "Abbott",
    phone: "888 123 4567",
    email: "abbott@whosonfirst.co",
    friends: ["Costello", "Laurel"]
  },
  {
    name: "Costello",
    phone: "767 676 7676",
    email: "costello@imonfirst.co",
    friends: ["Abbott", "Laurel"]
  }
];

/* You should be changing this code */

function findFriend(data, name, field) {
  let res = null; // будет результатом
  data.forEach(function(e) {
  
    if (e.name === name) { // прохожу по всем данным и ищу по name
      let friend = e.friends[0]; // отбираю первого друга

      data.forEach(ee => {
        if (ee.name === friend) { // ищу друга по name во всех данных
          res = ee[field]; // когда нашел - получаю нужное поле и записываю в результат
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return res; // возвращаю результат
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log(findFriend(contacts, "Abbott", "phone"));
});
```

Comment: Имя еще нужно вернуть, помимо телефона: `// returns {name: "Costello", phone: "767 676 7676"}`

Comment: @РустамГимранов и с какой проблемой вы столкнулись? я и так написал много...вам осталось чутка добавить

Comment: Да это не я вопрос задавал ) Просто неточность увидел, подметил.

Comment: @РустамГимранов прошу прощения ) думал вы задавали )